# Add lists of lists together in numpy

Tags: python, numpy

I have this

```
tmp0 = np.array([[a,b],[c,d],[e,f],...,[...]])
```

I want to take out a value, say [a,b] and compare it to [c,d] to make stuff simple, than add those two to the end of a new array as a 3D list

```
tmp1 = np.array([[[...],[...]],[[a,b],[c,d]]])
```

This have been proven to be a real horror show... How do I achieve this..? In just a regular array it would be append, but not in numpy for some odd reason

Comment: convert to regular array and append it then convert the final array to numpy array

Comment: The real question is: is numpy the right tool and are you aware of the consequences? Do you know the algorithmic complexity of changing numpy-array sizes (resizing is very costly)? In numpy world that's probably a case for concatenate, stack (hstack in this case; i think it will get deprecated someday) and all those. But think about my first sentences as well.

Comment: I am new in numpy, just fought arrays worked the same way. Might have to pick up a book or something to get more familiar with it. Edit: Atm I just use there documentation

Comment: numpy arrays provide more guarantees (about internal storage) compared to python-lists to speed up common functions. There is probably much to tell. But it boils down to contiguous-memory (which means: resizing = new array + copy all values + delete old array; compare with C/C++/Fortran arrays). That does not mean you can't do what you want (i mentioned some functions). But it means: doing this often (e.g. in loop) you are better of using python-lists in most cases.

Comment: Show us what you'd do with lists.  Then we can suggest a numpy alternative, if that is feasible and/or faster.